# 2 Jquery in one asp.net page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

i have Accordion menu and Datepicker i put all the .js file in one folder named Jquery. When running the page that has both the jqueries the Datepicker works fine but The accordion menu doesn't work properly.

- $(document).ready(function () {
                 $(".topnav").accordion({
                     accordion: false,
                     speed: 500,
                     closedSign: '[+]',
                     openedSign: '[-]'
                 });
             });

  $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#TxtBoxDOB").datepicker({
                 changeMonth: true,
                 changeYear: true,
                 showButtonPanel: true,
                 yearRange: '1940:2040'
             });
         });

  .ui-datepicker { 
        font-size:72.5%;
        background-color:ActiveBorder; 
        color:Maroon;
       font-family:Verdana;
                     }

Comment: Didn't you already ask that question like 5 mins ago ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824706/problems-with-2-jquery-in-one-page

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.  Update the old question with clarifications (which someone has kindly done for you, actually) to improve it.  A question can be re-opened if it's clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You have two handlers defined for the document.ready() event...try combining the events that should occur when the document is ready into the same event:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".topnav").accordion( { 
        accordion: false, 
        speed: 500,   
        closedSign: '[+]', 
        openedSign: '[-]' }); 
    $("#TxtBoxDOB").datepicker( { 
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        showButtonPanel: true, 
        yearRange: '1940:2040' });
});
```

Comment: While that might condense the code slightly (and have an imperceptible performance improvement since there'd only be one handler instead of two), what actual difference would it make?  `$(document).ready()` can be given as many functions as one wants.

Comment: i already tried it still not working properly :(

Comment: @David ahhh so it can....I'm no JQuery/Javascript expert, but I had never seen someone give document.ready() two functions separately (only inside of the same statement) and assumed there was a reason.  Thanks for the clarification, I've got some homework to do.

Comment: @user2612907: The problem isn't the `document.ready` event, the problem is that you're loading multiple versions of jQuery and jQuery UI into the same page.  This is being addressed in the original question.  (And this is why you shouldn't ask the same question multiple times, because people are already trying to help you on the first one.)